# Bash displaying a date and time value from a webpage

Tags: bash

```
<caption align="Top">
            Class Timetable was last refreshed on 04/05/2015 11:18AM
        </caption><tr class="OptionRow">
```

I would like to extract just the date and time value. 04/05/2015 11:18AM

I had used grep, sed, cat with | cat but they didnt work.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ grep -Eo '([[:digit:]]{2}/){2}[[:digit:]]{4} [[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}[AP]M' file
04/05/2015 11:18AM
```

Or:

```
$ sed -nr 's|.*(([[:digit:]]{2}/){2}[[:digit:]]{4} [[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}[AP]M).*|\1|p' file
04/05/2015 11:18AM
```